# Adding horizontal lines to timeseries plot with python + matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I am plotting data from a time series and I would like to add multiple horizontal lines, indicating value thresholds.

How do you recommend going about it?

```
date_today = datetime.now()
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1989', end='1/2/1989', freq='H')[:-1]
np.random.seed(seed=100)
data1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(date_rng))
data2 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(date_rng))
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': date_rng, 'col1': data1, 'col2': data2})
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.plot(figsize=(10, 5));
```

[image: tti]

Comment: Check the docs for `axhline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the axhline like this:

```
plt.axhline(xmin,xmax,y)
```

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html